# Insert data in local system but not inserted in live in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my codeigniter application data is inserted to database in my local system but on live data is not inserted into database and no error is occurred, how to debug?

Comment: Yes error reporting is on.

Comment: Can we see some code if possible ?

Comment: i got solution and i cross post limit data in form.

Comment: That is cool. You can add an answer of your own here and accept it or you can delete this question too. Its up to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross the post data limit due to data is not inserted,I change it and it's working now.